# Show only Questions Title on Questions View as User Choice

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, views, information-display

Could we get the view we have when we first sign into the site (with the question **title** text only), even when we hit the Questions button (when it changes to also showing the first line or so of the question)?  It'd be nice to be able to set some viewing preferences.

**This is so I can see the 'Newest' Questions page with the homepage view.**

Comment: I want this too! I want the compact view. I also want more than 50 questions. And I want when I click 'next' at the bottom to actually give me the **next** questions, not the same questions I just looked at because it took me a few minutes to read through them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the big site logo in the top left of the page.

---

Okay, he wants the format of the home page applied to the "New Questions" view.  This is a request that was declined way back in the Uservoice days.

Comment: That doesn't let you view the 'New' questions, which is what I'm usually interested in.

Comment: I'm not sure what magical question list you're talking about. From what I can tell it's the homepage.

Comment: Yes, but look at the format differences in the question list, between hitting the question button, and hitting the logo.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand you now.  You want the questions from the new questions page in the format from the home page?

Comment: Yep, that's it, thanks for rolling back the s-c tag.

Comment: :) Now that I understand what you want, I completely agree: this is a feature I asked for back on a UV a long time ago.

Comment: @Joel, how about editing your answer with the insight you had gained in the last comment, so I can accept it.