# compact list as a front page

Tags: feature-request, homepage

Would it be possible to have a more compact view of the question on the front page, as an option ? The gigantic vote number and views, could be made smaller. Focus only on the title and the author (tags are sort of redundant, as the page depends on your tag filtering, and the title normally says it all).

Comment: A lot of users don't do tag filtering, so I don't think taking out the tags would be helpful, especially since people are encouraged to use the tags instead of putting keywords in titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close to [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6382/homepage-view-as-default), check it out.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like you want the Questions page to mimic the front page, but it sounds like Stefano wants the front page to be even more compact.

Comment: hmm, good point, I'll edit my answer