# "Default" view vs "Questions" view

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design

While the screen caps are from superuser, this request is for all sites. A "site wide preference" would be nice.

In order to maximize vertical screen space, I would like to use a horizontally friendly view:

I much prefer this:

[alt text http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/5940/picture2zxx.png](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/5940/picture2zxx.png)

To this:

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/1962/picture1dsp.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/1962/picture1dsp.png)

I'm talking purely about the vote/answer/views display, not the "preview" of the question.

Comment: IMO, if you don't like the view on that page, don't go to that page.  Otherwise, there are always Greasemonkey and Stylish on Firefox.

Comment: @gclaghorn I don't have a choice but to go to that page for "Questions" -> "Newest".

Comment: You're right, more screenspace is always needed, see the link in my comment down below.

Comment: @Lance despite high resolution monitors, every pixel counts, especially in the age of super large verbose graphics that we're in now ;).

Answer (score 1):

I *prefer* the more-vertical, questions-page version because it includes preview text. I guess we *both* can choose what we prefer.

But I always wondered why the tab selections are different between those two pages.

```
    Front Page:  active,  featured,  hot,   week,   month
Questions Page:  newest,  featured,  hot,   votes,  active
```

Comment: We definitely need a Front Page-newest view, as per this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6382/homepage-view-as-default

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy the extra context provided on the questions page. I want to know more than just the title of the question before I jump in and try to answer it. The post preview is usually enough to give me an idea of whether or I should bother reading the question.