# Do you find new tag info annoying?

Tags: discussion, usability, feedback

Though I think that it's useful to provide information on what the tag is about, always displaying it on top of the page is really annoying.

Can you move it to a side space?

For me, having tag info at the top of the page means that I see one less question when I browse to a page, and because I usually know what **java** or **c** usually means I don't need to be reminded every time I see the page.

Comment: Yes, but maybe not for the same reason, I preferred it how it was with the info and stats tabs accessible through clicking the tag.

Comment: When I saw the "Please do not use this tag..." message at the top of the [not-programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/not-programming-related) tag page, I nearly sprained my index finger from trying to upvote it so hard.  It's hazardous!  ;)

Comment: Info and Stats never really fitted in the UI ... not-programming-related should really be blacklisted ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

[image]

Unobtrusive, yet obvious and readily accessible.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I found the huge blob on the Java wiki excerpt distasteful and noisy.

[image: Before]

I went ahead and edited it to something more visually pleasing:

[image: After]

Less space, less noise, much prettier.

We really want users to browse around this new section, the new answers and hot answer links provide lots of value for existing seasoned users of the tag.

To achieve the `excerpt` trick I used on Java I added a new meta tag to the tag wiki.

If you type

```
<excerpt>Tag excerpt here</excerpt>
```

In the wiki, it will use that text for the excerpt. This allows a lot more flexibility when authoring this stuff.

I would like to avoid adding any more user options, its a slippery slope and [ends here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/what-can-we-learn-from-quora/44641#44641).

If we move this to the side bar, below ads, nobody is going to look at it.

Comment: Now it screws actual content of the info page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info

Comment: @Silent I fixed Python, will simplify this stuff next week

Answer (score 2):

I think adding it at the top should at best be an option.

Stackoverflow is designed to be the expert site.  Experts in java/perl/whatever know what it is, probably much better (or at least in a more argumentative way) than any Wiki article.  The information is useless at best.

For those who aren't experts they should have at least an idea of what are appropriate tags.  Even if we don't, those who have sufficient reputation can add tags and thus steer the questions in the right direction.

Based on that I don't find any value add to the tag descriptions, but do see downsides like distraction and loss of screen area.

Comment: +1. Nice proposal to make it a user option, with 'ON' by default.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making it collapsible. While all those links are useful, they're not used that often and for people who monitor certain tags, loss of vertical screen estate is just painful.

P.S. I'd suggest making interesting/ignored tags collapsible as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of people who come here looking for answers that aren't experts.  Some of that information is important to let them know how that tag works on SO.  For an example of useful Meta information on how to tag see the [Excel info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel).

What I think would help with the space is if you could get [truncated listings like the home page on the questions page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6382/show-only-questions-title-on-questions-view-as-user-choice).

Comment: If you use the feeds, you can view 'em however you want...

Answer (score 1):

> Though I think that it's useful to provide information on what the tag is about, always displaying it on top of the page is really annoying.

Keep in mind, this thing was *just* turned on. It'll take a bit of time for the wikis to adjust such that the excerpt is actually useful.

And yeah, it may never be useful to *you*, at least not for the tags you're most active in. Comfort yourself with the thought that, just *maybe*, it'll remind a few other users that the [c] tag doesn't belong on every C++ question.

That said, it doesn't really bother me. It's smaller *and* less gaudy than the "sponsored tag links" boxes, and I got used to seeing *those*. And you'll be happy to know that you get one or the other, but never *both*.