# Request to add a short tag description (summary) for display on tag's questions page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki

I noticed that recently, when viewing the questions for a tag, a tag description is displayed (taken from "info" wiki, for example https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info for [perl] tag).

The problem is that this description is displayed as a non-formatted text content of the info wiki, which for some tags makes it fairly unreadable AND too long - as an example of Perl one, this is the text that is displayed, as-is, at the beginning of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl :

> Perl is a high-level, general-purpose,
>   interpreted, dynamic programming
>   language. Perl was originally
>   developed by Larry Wall in 1987 as a
>   general-purpose Unix scripting
>   language to make report processing
>   easier. ( copied from Wikipedia )
>   Latest stable release: 5.12.1 Latest
>   development releases: 5.13.* Related
>   tags: cpan The Comprehensive Perl
>   Archive Network dbi
>   Database-independent interface for
>   Perl mod-perl Integrate Perl and the
>   Apache web ...

My proposal would be to have a special text-only "short description"/"executive summary" for each tag - possibly stored in the tag's info wiki as a special section - which would be used in the tag description instead of a full text content of the entire wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put short text inside of `<excerpt>` tags in the wiki page:

```
<excerpt>Perl is awesome, but not as awesome as C++.</excerpt>
```

Just the text inside the `<excerpt>` tags will be displayed at the top of the pages.

For an example, see [the C++ page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++).

(I found out about this feature from [this post by waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62430/do-you-find-new-tag-info-annoying/62475#62475)).