# Markup between excerpt tags is not stripped

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

This is related to [waffles post 2 days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62430/do-you-find-new-tag-info-annoying/62475#62475).

Easier to explain by [seeing yourself on the ActiveSync tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activesync).

```
ActiveSync is a mobile [data synchronization][1] technology and [protocol][2] developed by [Microsoft][3]
```

I imagine because the excerpt tag on the tag wiki is new, that this portion might of been overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the instance, but the mechanism for excerpts is brutally confusing.

<strike>I will add a field for excerpts later on today.</strike> done

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asmx. Excerpt doesn't work. What'd I do wrong?

Comment: @John try editing it again, there is a box on top of the wiki that contains the excerpt ... I fixed it up for asmx