# Default sort order for main page on SO is completely broken/wrong

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, sorting, homepage

The times are all over the place.

- Moderation tools for django apps ? 4m ago
- Using fixed text together with <%# when databinding in Asp.NET doesn't work 2m ago
- Looking for alternative PHP fgetcsv() function to handlle textfiles 2m ago
- How do i process date and time on sql and php  1m ago
- To filter contents of table column using Open XML 5m ago
- How upload folder by FTP using cURL? 5m ago
- Switch Application.Mainform at runtime and invoke MainformOnTaskBar cause flickering on Windows Taskbar 10m ago

Was fine still yesterday.

Comment: [status-by-design](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/266689#266689), apparently :)

Comment: It's been fixed, it was actually broken before.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: So how do I get it back? I have been using the site as it was for 18 months now.  The other views are not sufficient for me.

Comment: @leppie http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active

Comment: The button way to get it back (where Yi's link goes) is to hit the Questions button, then the Active tab.  Two differences are that it will have pages, where the old homepage had only 1 long page, and you'll get the first lines of the question.

Comment: @Yi Jiang & @Lance Roberts: The view is completely different. The questions are about double the size in height. That I DO NOT want. I want the L&F of the front page.

Comment: @Yi Jiang & @Lance Roberts: That view also only shows only the last 5 minutes, also not the same as the previous homepage view.

Comment: I've always hated that I can't get just the questions titles showing on that other page either, as per this [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6382/show-only-questions-title-on-questions-view-as-user-choice).

Comment: Read [all about it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/)

Comment: @Jeff - Can we have the "Active" tab *as well* as the "Interesting" tab? Surely it's not an either/or situation.

Comment: Actually, I like the ordering. I've instantly much more questions to answer without the need to browse by tags :)

Comment: @ChrisF: Even better, allow the user to set the default tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can get the old page:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=active
```

Comment: Awesome!!  :) ____

Comment: Actually, the default is now back to 'normal' again. Oh well  ;P